# Ubuntu doesn't load desktop at all after login screen

Tags: 12.04, unity, ati, compiz, system

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 for more than 1 year on my Dell N5010 laptop. It was OK yesterday morning, but when I wanted to save my VirtualBox session, it gaves me an error ( i don't remember exactly but it was about saving in low disk ) and after that I missed my whole desktop. After I restarted my laptop, couldn't load my main user but the guest user works flawlessly. My mouse is enabled there, but I can't have my desktop properly.

I've tried all the solutions that found in this forum but none of them were suitable for this problem. Let me list the things I've done:

- Upgraded all the packages
- Removed `lightdm` and reinstalled it
- Remove all the ATI card packages
- Removed whole Compiz configuration for the user
- Removed `compizconfig-setting-manager` and reinstalled it
- Unity won't load at all with `unity --reset`, `unity --replace`, `setsid unity`

At first i thought this problem is for the low space . so i moved some of my files and deleted some by using Ctrl+Alt+F1 and made 22G new space on root.result of `df -h`:

```
> Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3        45G   20G   23G  47% /
udev            1.9G  4.0K  1.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           764M  948K  764M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            1.9G  292K  1.9G   1% /run/shm
/dev/sda8        81G   29G   52G  36% /Server
none            1.9G   52M  1.9G   3% /tmp/guest-dXl9aQ
/dev/sda6        81G   78G  2.8G  97% /media/Software
/dev/sda9        76G   71G  4.5G  95% /media/Tutorials
/dev/sdc1       7.6G  4.9G  2.7G  65% /media/4861-3CF0
/dev/sda10       11G  8.8G  1.8G  84% /media/New Volume
/dev/sda5        81G   77G  3.5G  96% /media/Install
```

however i've tried all the desktops that i've installed but only blackbox and recovery-mode work .
I think it's a problem with `dbus-launcher` because when I want to load `compizconfig-setting-manager`, it says "can't connect to dbus-deamon". I went through [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears) and tried most of the replies but couldn't get to a proper solution. These are the steps:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
ccsm
```

result :

```
Backend     : ini
Integration : true
Profile     : default
Adding plugins
Initializing core options...done
Segmentatui fault (core dumped)
```

then :

> unity --reset
>   result :

```
Checking if settings need to be migrated ...no
Checking if internal files need to be migrated ...no
unity-panel-service: no process found
Backend     : gconf
Integration : true
Profile     : unity
Adding plugins
Initializing core options...done
Initializing composite options...done
WARNING: Unity currently default profile, so switching to metacity while resetting the values
Segmentatui fault (core dumped)
```

then

```
unity --replace
```

result :

```
unity-panel-service: no process found
Checking if settings need to be migrated ...no
Checking if internal files need to be migrated ...no
Backend     : gconf
Integration : true
Profile     : unity
Adding plugins
Initializing core options...done
Initializing composite options...done
Initializing opengl options...done
Initializing decor options...done
Initializing vpswitch options...done
Initializing snap options...done
Initializing mousepoll options...done
Initializing resize options...done
Initializing place options...done
Initializing move options...done
Initializing wall options...done
Initializing grid options...done
Initializing session options...done
Initializing gnomecompat options...done
Initializing animation options...done
Initializing fade options...done
Initializing unitymtgrabhandles options...done
Initializing workarounds options...done
Initializing scale options...done
compiz (expo) - Warn: failed to bind image to texture
Initializing expo options...done
Initializing ezoom options...done
Segmentatui fault (core dumped)
```

then

> unity --reset-icons

result :

```
unity-panel-service: no process found
Checking if settings need to be migrated ...no
Checking if internal files need to be migrated ...no
Backend     : gconf
Integration : true
Profile     : unity
Adding plugins
Initializing core options...done
Initializing composite options...done
Initializing opengl options...done
Initializing decor options...done
Initializing vpswitch options...done
Initializing snap options...done
Initializing mousepoll options...done
Initializing resize options...done
Initializing place options...done
Initializing move options...done
Initializing wall options...done
Initializing grid options...done
Initializing session options...done
Initializing gnomecompat options...done
Initializing animation options...done
Initializing fade options...done
Initializing unitymtgrabhandles options...done
Initializing workarounds options...done
Initializing scale options...done
compiz (expo) - Warn: failed to bind image to texture
Initializing expo options...done
Initializing ezoom options...done
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I've tried some other solution on that page like installing packages or removing configuration and such things but none of them was helpful.

Comment: please read the question carefully . i've done all the stuffs on that page. it doesn't help me at all bro !!!

Comment: You're right, but i didn't mention other stuffs that i've done in the question.It's really strange that it works with guest users without any problem but not with my main user.i don't remember  the VBox error exactly , but i think it was about saving in low disk.however i've tried all the desktops that i've installed but only blackbox and recovery-mode works , lol .

Comment: @EliahKagan : in fact i want to know where is problem, because i think it's a bug in ubuntu systems. what u think ?

Comment: At first i thought this problem is for the low space . so i moved some of my files and deleted some by using Ctrl+Alt+F1 and made 22G new space on root. however i added the result on the question. .

Comment: You're right to think 22 GB is enough free space! (Significantly, the results you've added to your question so there's no separate `/home` partition, indicating `/home` is on `/` and thus that there's enough free space in your home directory.) I recommend adding the information you've provided in comments to your question as well (including about the "Ubuntu 2D" session type not working either, if it didn't; this way comments can be cleaned up and it'll be easier for others to help.  Also, *had* you tried deleting/renaming `.Xauthority` and reinstalling `unity` with the `--purge` flag?

Comment: If you add details about those things to your question (and you tried them and they didn't work), I'll make sure to remove my close vote. (This may one day be duped to that, but it shouldn't be closed while the problem is still unsolved if not answered in the other question.) I recommend adding links to questions (or forum posts elsewhere) whose proposed solutions you've tried, especially if there are any *other* than [that big one](http://askubuntu.com/q/17381). Do I think this is a bug? Likely yes. Even the easily solvable cases I think represent bugs. But we shouldn't close this as a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to go for the simple, raw solution:
Restart your system in safe mode (F8 after the BIOS startup), enter in a root terminal with networking capabilities and write:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop unity
```

And see what happens. This should restore all the dependencies.

Comment: Thanks man, but i want to know where is the problem . because i can reinstall the ubuntu too , lol :)

Comment: however it loads flawlessly on the guest user

Comment: jaj, ok then just run a root session in failure-proof mode and type startx, you will see the log in there, right? Obviously if the problem isn't in the guest session then you corrupted your session settings... So I'll have to agree with @Kiwi´ s proposal.

Comment: unfortunately it didn't help me the @kiwi solution but i created a root user again with another name and it works good , so i'm restoring my configuration to this new account. This was only helpful solution that i got to .

Answer (score 0):

Make a backup of the following folder from your home folder :
`.gnome .gnome2 .gconf .gconfd .metacity`

then delete them :

`rm -rf .gnome .gnome2 .gconf .gconfd .metacity`

Try to login again and I bet it will work. if not, restore your backup.

---

Edit:
when the very same issue occure last time it was because I had no more space disk on my `/home` partition

Comment: unfortunately,you lost (il ne fonctionne pas),lol :D

Comment: c'est si évident que je suis français ?

Comment: no at all , lol